# Is there a LaTeX package for conference event programs?

Tags: packages

I'm helping to organize a symposium, and I'd like to generate the event programs with LaTeX.  Is there an appropriate package for this, or should I do it by hand?  Thanks in advance!

Comment: It depends on what exactly you need, if you only need a schedule or if you'll need to add the abstracts, for example. You should provide more information. (Perhaps a [CTAN search](http://www.ctan.org/search/) could be enough.)

Comment: A lot depends on what goes into the program. I would be inclined to generate the programs as a table using the `longtable` package (assuming they might span mulitple pages) and use the `datatool` package to read a CSV file containing the schedule information itself. Then its easy to generate new schedules as the CSV data is updated.

Answer (score 6):

Years ago I created a conference programme manual with the help of LaTeX. We used a self-developed online tool for the different sessions, so I asked the developer to give me a list of all days, rooms, session and presentations. I fed this list into my own MySQL database and with the help of PHP generated a series of SQL statements querying the days, rooms, sessions, etc. I generated then the necessary LaTeX code and pasted this directly into the programme. The big advantage was that with any change in the original database I just had to rerun my scripts.

If you are interested, have a look at the file http://uweziegenhagen.de/compstat/final8.pdf

Comment: I'll try to find the file again, I should have it somewhere.

Comment: The link is working again.

Comment: The link is non-working again, I’m afraid…

Comment: I have fixed it again. Sorry. Today I would not use PHP but Python with the pandas library instead.