# Is there a package or scripted solution to generate the program for scientific conferences

Tags: macros, packages, templates, scripts

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Is there a LaTeX package for conference event programs?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/45461/is-there-a-latex-package-for-conference-event-programs)

I am looking for a solution to generate the program to a scientific event with multiple conferences and workshops.

I would like to use a database or text files (even an Excel or OpenOffice spreadsheet file would be possible) to generate multiple things:

1. A complete scientific program, which could look like this:

   > ```
   > Conference XYZ
   >  Monday
   >   Session 1 - 08:00 - 10:00
   >     Paper Foo: Author 1, Author 2
   >   Cofeebreak
   >   ....
   > ```
2. Take only one day and generate the program for 1 day.
3. Generate a program for each conference (per day or the whole thing)

So what i need is some kind of template-framework that uses data I provide in some kind of data structure.

The program was done in MS Word up until now, which does not look that nice and I would like to change that.

Comment: Take a look at this question:  http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/45461/is-there-a-latex-package-for-conference-event-programs

Comment: I also recommend the flyer of Predrag given in http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/51725/3235